# Set a default result type for a package

Tags: java, configuration, struts2

I'm reading the struts' guide about `result`s [here](https://struts.apache.org/docs/result-configuration.html#ResultConfiguration-IntelligentDefaults).

It says:

> Each package may set a default result type to be used if none is specified in a result element. If one package extends another, the "child" package can set its own default result, or inherit one from the parent.

and after it shows the following code:

```
public Result runAction() {
    ServletDispatcherResult result = new ServletDispatcherResult();
    result.setLocation("input-form.jsp");
    return result;
}
```

But I can't understand how this code can set a default result type for the actions in a package. Can anyone explain me?

Comment: What are you expecting from this question? It is just a misplaced piece of code which belongs to *Returning Result Objects* section. See correct version here - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Result+Configuration.

Comment: Struts2 wiki pages are loading code to the document dynamically, thus the error is the fragment  of code belongs to another section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code *doesn't* set the default result type. To set the default result type you can use the code

```
PackageConfig.Builder packageConfig = new PackageConfig.Builder(packageName).defaultResultType(resultTypeName);
```

---

With `XmlConfigurationProvider` both package name and result type name are defined by the `name` attribute. The `result-type` tag has also the attribute `default`. It has a string `true` or any other value that is used to determine a default result type for the package.